# Using a Docker image to build and deploy as part of a build matrix

Tags: docker, travis-ci

Is it possible to use a Docker image as part of a build matrix to test and deploy?

I have a standard, functioning build matrix and deploy step for releases, but I need to swap out the Linux build for a specific container (available on quay.io).

```
matrix:
  include:
    - os: osx
      rust: stable
      env: TARGET=x86_64-apple-darwin
    - os: linux
      rust: stable
      env: TARGET=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    # and some more

before_deploy:
  - bash ci/before_deploy.sh

before_install:
  - export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.cargo/bin"

install:
  - bash ci/install.sh

script:
  - bash ci/script.sh

deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key:
        - secure: xxx
  file_glob: true
  file: ${PROJECT_NAME}-${TRAVIS_TAG}-${TARGET}.*
  # don't delete the artifacts from previous phases
  skip_cleanup: true
  # deploy when a new tag is pushed
  on:
    tags: true
```

What I'd like to do is substitute a Docker image for the `os: linux` build, and run the scripts inside it. Is this even possible, though? All the examples I've seen prepend script steps with the `docker` command, and provide it as a `service`, which will fail for non-Docker builds.